# Flash CS5 compiler options broken?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

(Haven't received any love on Adobe forums, so trying this here)

So, I've formally logged a bug against this with Adobe as I've been beating my head against a wall trying to understand why this won't work, but I'm hoping that it's perhaps something within the Flash IDE that I'm setting incorrectly (or not setting at all) that is causing the issue that I'm encountering:

I've created a container .fla that uses classes that are defined in an externally loaded swc, child.swc. I've added the .swc in the container's library path (Publish Settings > AS 3.0 Settings > Library Path) and have set its "Link Type" as "Exernal". According to [Adobe's docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fa4a.html):

> "External: The code resources found in the path are not added to the
>   published SWF file, but the compiler verifies that they are in the
>   locations you specified."

However, when using FlashDevelop's swf browsing utility after publishing the fla (and having used a reference to the class in the container class), I see that the class definition is still being added to container.swf.

Now, if I use compc and mxmlc with the appropriate options (-link-report and -load-externs), I can exclude child classes as needed and all functions as expected. However, when setting what seems to be the same options in the Flash IDE, it does not provide the same output. Unfortunately, I have some use cases where the use of the Flash IDE is essential, so a workaround would be painful.

Is this a known issue, or is there something that I'm just doing wrong (or are my expectations incorrect) in the IDE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen if you set the type to RSL instead?

Comment: Yes, the class definitions are included in the output with any of the "Link Type" options being set.

Answer (score 0):

have you made sure, that these classes are not accidentally included in your source path?

Also, try setting the flex sdk in the Flash IDE (Settings > ActionScript > ActionScript 3.0 Settings). Then try again publishing, it will now use the flex compiler.